# not sure why my loadmatcheswithmatchdata isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I'm creating a public method to return all of my matches from my gamecenterhelper.m

I have this:

```
+(NSArray *)retrieveMatchesWithMatchData {
    __block NSArray *myMatches = nil;
    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error loading matches");
        }
        else {
            myMatches = matches;
        }
    }];
    return myMatches;
}
```

but this returns null when I call it, even though I have active matches.  the call method looks like this:

```
NSLog(@"My matches: %@",[GameCenterHelper retrieveMatchesWithMatchData]);
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the nature of blocks. Your block is executed asynchronously. You cannot load Game Center matches synchronously. Let's make this an instance method:

```
-(void)retrieveMatchesWithMatchData {
    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error loading matches");
        }
        else {
            [self matchesLoaded:matches];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then you process the matches in this method:

```
-(void)matchesLoaded:(NSArray *)matches {
    //do something with your matches
}
```

EDIT:

There is an easy way to do what you want. You can use Apples standard view controller to show current matches:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init]; 
request.minPlayers = minPlayers;     
request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = 
[[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] 
 initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;
mmvc.showExistingMatches = YES;
[self presentViewController:mmvc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: so there is no way for me to just pass an array of matches (short of creating another array and adding all matches 1 by 1)?

Comment: I'm trying to create a view that shows the users current matches.  I'd like to keep the game center stuff in the gamecenterhelper pages.  Is this not how most would go about this?

Comment: You can use delegation for that. In the `matchesLoaded:` method you can pass the matches to delegate. To know more about delegates read [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) doc from Apple.